# best way to notify view that a job is done in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails question:  A user uploads an image to a rails server.  I am doing some thumbnail crunching in the background in rails (async, using the DelayedJob gem).  When it is finished, I'd like to notify the view that it's done so the thumbnail can be displayed.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of images are you uploading? If it's just one, I think it would be easiest to just crunch the thumbnail then redirect the user to the landing page.

Comment: We are submitting multiple images.  And we need an Ajax update, not a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some sort of pub/sub service to do this. Two example services

- http://faye.jcoglan.com/ *(open source)*
- http://pubnub.com *(pay service with free plan)*

Your view will include the "subscribe" part of the pub/sub model (Javascript API). Your job will "publish" the notification to the channel stating it's finished it's work. The Javascript subscriber in your view will trigger a callback that you define to do whatever you want (ie. display the thumbnail).